# create a hyperlinked value in excel generated by sql query data connection

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I was wondering if it possible to generate a excel data with a hyperlinked value in one of its column from sql query data connection.

here's my example

```
  select CUSTID,'=HYPERLINK("http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=,'||CUSTID ||'",' || CUSTID ||')' AS CustidURL
```

FROM sometable

expected output

```
  ---------------
  |custidURL    |
  ---------------
  123405 < - hyperlinked value
```

I was able to run the query but the value is as is like this

```
    =HYPERLINK("http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=123405",123405)
```

Comment: Not with a data query.  Excel will treat the input as text and not as a formula.  Other options are to add a computed columns outside of the query range or use a macro to transform the text into a formula reference.

Comment: this is what I have in mind. coz it only works once I clicked on the check icon in fomula bar.